# Is there any tool available in linux which can generate flowchart from C code?

Tags: 16.04, c, open-source

I need to create flowcharts for C code which i wrote for my project.
I was searching for free software in linux which can do the task for me.
and i came across Dia ,but it is not automatic flowchart generator.
also i tried online tool like code2flow,but it will generate ".png" or pdf format of flowchart,which i dont wan't.I want to generate flowchart which i should be able to export to word document,and if some one want to change/edit some part flowchart he should be able to edit it(so iam avoiding img files).
Please suggest me proper tool.

Comment: This sounds like task for [GraphViz](https://www.graphviz.org/gallery/) with some scripting or existing tools (search for them).

Comment: is that opensource ?

Comment: Yes, it is - see official site or [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphviz).

Comment: Founder of code2flow here - is it missing any functionality or are you specifically looking for Free Software? Results from code2flow can definitely be embedded inside a Word document. btw. Word is not Free Software :-)

Comment: Code2flow is great ..What i felt  it should generate a file which can be editable in word or any other document to which we are going to import .But it produces flowchart in image format .Which is not modifiable